# The onLoadResource function sporadically generates not found errors

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview application that uses hooks to execute native java code (ie populate a local db) and to catch these hooks I use the `onLoadResource` function.

It works as expected, but about 10% of the time I get server log errors of the hook being fired and its clogging up my logs with "not found" errors.

So it basically works like this:

1. User loads their webview app
2. In the app they click on of the hooks (http://domain.com/hook/datatopass)
3. The `onLoadResource` does its processing and forwards the user to
   another page (http://domain.com/home)

The majority of the time it works, but sporadically I get the "ERROR [http://domain.com/hook/datatopass] not found" error.

From what I can tell the user doesn't see any error pages, they get forwarded to the correct place - but I don't know why the `onLoadResource` doesn't catch every request before it logs an error.  Anyone know how to avoid these errors being thrown, and why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It seems for me that a `Timeout` occurs - sometimes. 
Have you tried to set the timeout time higher ?

Or have you tried to show an ProgressDialog like below to locate the problem?

```
 public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            // Check to see if there is a progress dialog
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                // If no progress dialog, make one and set message
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading please wait...");
                progressDialog.show();

                // Hide the webview while loading
                webview.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
```